# Ask about bandwidth consumption tracking is on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like know if ask about bandwidth consumption tracking does part content of community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the question *directly* related to security? That's the only test.

There are lots of questions where the answer can be *applied* to security, but those are not security questions.

For instance, suppose a firewall appliance is plugged into a faulty power outlet. Questions about how to fix the power outlet are off-topic.

If your question is about *how* to track bandwidth consumption because you want to use that information to calculate unauthorised use, this is off-topic. It's not a security question but a networking question that has a potential security application.

Comment: Could like help me a formulate one ask on topic about bandwidth? I trying but without sucess.  https://security.stackexchange.com/q/174543/164782

Comment: Nothing about that question is about security

Comment: yes, could give some suggestion for improve? for become on-topic

Comment: Sure. First tell me how your question relates to security.

Comment: In this case bandwidth it is related with network private, I believe that the question about "bandwidth control" then avoid that users use more bandwidth than the allowed this is within information security

Comment: But that is not what your question is about. Limiting a user to a max bandwidth so that they cannot overwhelm the connection is one thing. You want to place a limit on how much throughput over time. There is nothing about 'availability' in that question. As others have said, you can look at the network engineering site for this type of question.

Comment: Ok thanks, indeed I published wrong here